# angular 13 - insert incoming json object into model

Tags: json, angular

With angular, I am getting data as follows through the api. Everything works very well, but I cannot place the incoming json object into the model. I can't find where I made a mistake. Can you provide support?

```
 export class DialogBoxComponent implements OnInit {
   workflows: WorkflowListModel[] = [];


  constructor(
    public workflowService: WorkflowListService
  ) {
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.workflowService.getWorkflowDefinitions().subscribe(data => {
      this.workflows = data.items;
      console.log(this.workflows);
  });

 }
```

**Service**

```
public getWorkflowDefinitions(){
  let api = `${this.apiUrl}/services/workflows`;
  return this.httpClient.get<{items: WorkflowListModel[]}>(api).pipe(tap(x =>{
    this.loading = false;
    console.log();
  }));
}
```

**Model**

```
export class WorkflowListModel {
  id: string | any;
  definitionId: string | any;
  name: string | any;
  displayName: string | any;
  description: string | any;
  version: number | any;
  persistenceBehavior: string | any;
  isPublished: string | any;
  isLatest: string | any;
}
```

**json-result**

```
[
    {
        "id": "fb40d5c146644e58b05e2cb573409bbc",
        "definitionId": "336507c20553401f85d3b2b4e11a562c",
        "name": "demand",
        "displayName": "demand",
        "description": "demand",
        "version": 1,
        "isSingleton": false,
        "persistenceBehavior": "Suspended",
        "isPublished": true,
        "isLatest": true
    }
]
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="{{action}}" matInput [formControl]="myControl"
       [matAutocomplete]="auto">
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions" [value]="option">
    {{option}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

[image]

this way a json object comes and i can access the items in this object

```
 {
  "items": [
     {
        "id": "fb40d5c146644e58b05e2cb573409bbc",
        "definitionId": "336507c20553401f85d3b2b4e11a562c",
        "name": "demand",
        "displayName": "demand",
        "description": "demand",
        "version": 1,
        "isSingleton": false,
        "persistenceBehavior": "Suspended",
        "isPublished": true,
        "isLatest": true
    }
  ],
  "totalCount": 1
 }
```

Comment: yes, the items objects are coming as above and I can access the items objects directly. I can view it on the console. But it does not transfer these incoming objects into the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start off by saying you have quite a strange implementation.

This goes in your component :

```
public workflows: WorkflowListModel[] = [];

constructor(private workflowService: WorkflowListService) {
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.workflowService.getWorkflowDefinitions().subscribe(
        (data: WorkflowListModel[]) => this.workflows = data
    );
}
```

1. The service should not be public, you should not be able to access it from the HTML template, only from the component.
2. I would've created a private function that would get the workflows and call that function in the `ngOnInit()`
3. You might want to do error handling in case of an error

This goes in your service :

```
public getWorkflowDefinitions(): Observable<WorkflowListModel[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<WorkflowListModel[]>(`${this.apiUrl}/services/workflows`);
}
```

1. I used observables so you can retrieve the object type, again you had a strange implementation that I have never seen before
2. You were esentially retrieving an object of type `any` since you didn't specified anything
3. Why bother creating a variable with the API URL when you are only using it once?

This goes in your model class

```
export class WorkflowListModel {

   public id: any;
   public definitionId: any;
   public name: any;
   public displayName: any;
   public description: any;
   public version: any;
   public persistenceBehavior: any;
   public isPublished: any;
   public isLatest: any;

   constructor() {
   }
}
```

`any` means any type, so `string | any` it's pretty much useless, but I wouldn't use `any` since most likely there are only numbers and strings that you are working it